# What does "OS" mean on a Sigma lens?

Tags: terminology, sigma

I want to buy a Sigma 180mm F/2.8 EX DG Macro OS HSM Sigma.

What does EX mean?

What does DG mean?

What does OS mean?

What does HSM mean?

Comment: EX = high-end series, DG = full frame compatible, OS = optical stabilisation, HSM = hyper-sonic motor

Answer (score 0):

`OS` is *Optical Stabilization*, Sigma's term for a system which moves lens elements to compensate for small camera movements.